# Конструктор в AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Нашёл следующий класс для считывания html-страницы в строку

```
public class HTMLPageDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    public static interface HTMLPageDownloaderListener {
        public abstract void completionCallBack(String html);
    }
    public HTMLPageDownloaderListener listener;
    public String link;
    public HTMLPageDownloader (String aLink, HTMLPageDownloaderListener aListener) {
        listener = aListener;
        link = aLink;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
        String html = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream in;
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
            html = str.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return html;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            listener.completionCallBack(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь не пойму как с ним работать. Передать в конструктор ссылку могу, но откуда взять listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTMLPageDownloaderListener это интерфейс. Что он должен делать - решать вам. Чтобы передать его в конструктор вам надо его экземпляр создать. Например так:

```
 HTMLPageDownloader test = new HTMLPageDownloader("someUrl", new HTMLPageDownloaderListener(){
    @Override
    public void completionCallBack(String html)
    {
      System.out.print("Callback called");
    }
});
```